# datalist ng-repeat click doesn't update ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datalist

I am trying to create a textbox with an autocomplete from a list which is already on the client

```
<input list="Project" 
       name="Project" 
       type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       ng-model="request.projectFreeText">
<datalist id="Project">
    <option ng-repeat="project in test.projects" value="{{project.name}}">
</datalist>
```

Let's say my list is: `"abc", "def", "ghi"`.
my problem is if I type `"ab"` it will autocomplete it to `"abc"` but I need to click it with the mouse, but when I do, the value in the text wIll be `"abc"` and the value in ng-model will be `"ab"`.

Comment: there should be some a event when u select @yogi

Comment: It sounds like you are updating the text of the `<input>`, instead of updating the `model` attached to that `<input>`.

Comment: @JustinJmnz I think you are correct, how can I fix that?

Comment: @yogi Please post the javascript code for the `controller` that controls this piece of `html`. Also include the `html` code that surrounds the example provided already if possible.